# MS Flow SharePoint "Grant Access" action fails with "Item does not exist"

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm getting an error in my flow when using the `Grant Access to an item or folder` action to grant view access to an account on a list item.  I've tested this action on a SharePoint site (comm-site) configured exactly the same (99% certain) in the same tenant and it works fine.  In this instance, I have a `get item` action on the same `ID` right after it, and that action works fine.  The error that I get looks like this:

```
"body": {
    "error": {
      "code": 502,
      "source": "flow-apim-msmanaged-na-westus2-01.azure-apim.net",
      "clientRequestId": "9f16fa13-287c-441d-9331-3e7e93a5811f",
      "message": "BadGateway",
      "innerError": {
        "status": 500,
        "message": "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.\r\nclientRequestId: 9f16fa13-287c-441d-9331-3e7e93a5811f\r\nserviceRequestId: 9f16fa13-287c-441d-9331-3e7e93a5811f"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Request Ids (not sure which are important):

From inner error:

- `"clientRequestId": "9f16fa13-287c-441d-9331-3e7e93a5811f"`

From error response header:

- `"SPRequestGuid": "9f16fa13-287c-441d-9331-3e7e93a5811f"`
- `"request-id": "9f16fa13-287c-441d-9331-3e7e93a5811f"`

I'm not sure if this is the sharepoint API, or graph API under the hood - but the behaviour is completely stumped me and I have no clue what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the action and re-created it.  It worked fine after that.

This was likely my mistake: I had made this flow by exporting a flow from a solution ("solution-aware flow") and importing it is a regular flow.  There was a dialog that said "this is for importing normal flows, to import a flow from a solution go to solutions" which I .. disregarded.  The problem was likely a result of that mis-step.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, this issue happens when we try to grant access to a list item which does not exist. So make sure the list item with the ID exist in this list.

You could add a "Get item" action and use the id, check whether you could get the item with this id.

Comment: So I have a get item right before the action, and after it and both worked fine.  I probably discovered a bug though.  I deleted the action and re-created it - and it worked fine.  Some context, I exported and imported the flow from a "solution" into a normal flow.  I saw the message that said not to do that.  This error was probably related to that.